# Am I understanding the Decorator pattern correctly?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I'm learning the decorator pattern currently. I wrote this program to test my knowledge. Am I getting it right?

```
public interface Logger {
    void log(String msg);
}

public class BasicLogger implements Logger {

    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        System.out.println("BasicLogger: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Here is where I start getting confused, what's the point of the logger.log(msg) in the decorator if I'm going to override it anyway in the `HTMLLogger` class?

```
public class LoggerDecorator implements Logger {
    Logger logger;
    public LoggerDecorator(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        logger.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Am I even suppoed to duplicate the `logger.log(msg);` line (or whatever the decorator has)?

```
public class HTMLLogger extends LoggerDecorator {
    public HTMLLogger(Logger logger) {
        super(logger);
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        logger.log(msg);
        System.out.println("<HTML> HTML Logger" + msg);
        //Generate the html file
    }
}
```

Finally, in the demo class I have this:

```
public LoggerTest() {
    BasicLogger logger = new BasicLogger();
    Logger htmlLogger = new HTMLLogger(new BasicLogger());
    logger.log("Basic Logger log");
    htmlLogger.log("HTML Logging");
}
```

The output is:

```
BasicLogger: Basic Logger log
BasicLogger: HTML Logging
<HTML> HTML LoggerHTML Logging
```

I will really need to have a solid understanding of the decorator pattern, because I will need to implement it using AspectJ.

Comment: Yes you have it right. To a certain degree. Normally in your decorator or even in the children of the decorator you would want to put in logic of some type before letting the work take place in the super class. For instance in your HTML you might want to search for non-HTML friendly characters and replace them. Or add in validation, or support multiple output destinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you might be missing is a comment saying something like `/* your code here */` as instructions for what to do when subclassing.

```
public class LoggerDecorator implements Logger {
    Logger logger;
    public LoggerDecorator(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        
        /** YOUR CODE HERE WHEN SUBCLASSING **/
        
        /**
         * delegate to the base logger passed into the constructor to
         * perform existing logging operations.
         */
        logger.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Each time you call a decorator constructor, you pass in an existing logger. This logger is assigned to a private variable and is used in the overridden log method.  For each decoration, you add more functionality to the logger.log calls.

For example, when you instantiate your HTMLLogger, you're adding in a system.out message.  As an exercise, create another concrete logger called XMLLogger, like so:

```
public class XMLLogger extends LoggerDecorator {
    public XMLLogger(Logger logger) {
        super(logger);
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        logger.log(msg);
        System.out.println("<?xml version="1.0"?><message>XML Logger" + msg);
        //Generate the xml file
    }
}
```

and then add it to your test runner:

```
public LoggerTest() {
    BasicLogger logger = new BasicLogger();
    Logger htmlLogger = new HTMLLogger(new BasicLogger());
    Logger xmlAndHtmlLogger = new XMLLogger(new HTMLLogger());
    logger.log("Basic Logger log");
    htmlLogger.log("HTML Logging");
    xmlAndHtmlLogger.log("I am Both HTML and XML logging");
}
```

Output:

```
BasicLogger: Basic Logger log
BasicLogger: HTML Logging
<HTML> HTML LoggerHTML Logging

BasicLogger: I am Both HTML and XML logging
<HTML> HTML LoggerI am Both HTML and XML logging
<?xml version="1.0"?><message>XML LoggerI am Both HTML and XML logging
```

In the above output, I inserted a space simply to show you the output resulting from the xmlAndHtmlLogger.log method call.

The decorator pattern works by extending a base class, adding additional code to the overridden method, and then delegating back to the original.  So for each new decorator subclass you instantiate, you add more functionality to that overridden method.

Since xmlAndHtmlLogger was decorated with the HTMLLogger, which was subclassed from the base, we get all of the functionality of all three when invoking the method.  You can mix and match these decorator calls in any order to determine both the order of functionality or to even omit some functionality by leaving out one of the decorators.

---

#### Advantages of Decorator Pattern

I want to clarify that the advantage of the decorator pattern is that you can create different combinations of objects with different mix-and-match functionality, without necessarily creating N concrete subclasses for each combination. In this example, with the BaseLogger, HTMLLogger, and XMLLogger, we can create the following objects:

- A base logger that does nothing fancy.
- An HTML logger
- An XML logger
- An HTML logger that also handles XML!

That 4th item is important to note, as it's a combination of two of the decorations. Let's say we also added the following additional decorators:

- JSONLogger
- YAMLLogger

With these two additional decorators, we now can create the following objects at runtime:

- Base logger with nothing fancy.
- HTMLLogger
- XMLLogger
- HTML and XML Logger in one
- HTML and JSON Logger in one
- HTML and YAML Logger in one
- HTML and XML and JSON Logger in one
- HTML and XML and JSON and YAML in one
- etc

In short, instead of creating a concrete subclass for each desired combination, we simply create simple classes with basic functionality, then we add on extra functionality at runtime by chaining the created objects into the constructor of the next object.

Thus, 4 decorators could yield over 16 different combinations of loggers! That's a powerful concept, which can save a lot of coding time.

For more in-depth examples, see [Wikipedia's WindowScrolling Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#First_example_.28window.2Fscrolling_scenario.29), as well as the Coffee Example. Take note of the constructors in the test runner, where you can clearly see each object passed back into the constructor of the next class. This is the process of "decorating" an object.

Answer (score 2):

A decorator is simply a wrapper. The "wrapping" of an action (method) allows you to "intervene" the action by applying all sort of things before/after it takes place.

That in mind, let's take your first example and modify it to implement the decorator pattern (we can apply different implementations).

#### Using inheritance:

```
public class Logger {
    void log(String msg){
        System.out.println("msg = " + msg);
    };
}

public class BasicLogger extends Logger {

    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        System.out.println("BasicLogger - before logging: " + msg);
        super.log(msg);
        System.out.println("BasicLogger - after logging: " + msg);
    }
}
```

#### Using composition:

```
public class Logger {
    void log(String msg){
        System.out.println("msg = " + msg);
    };
}

public class BasicLogger {

    Logger logger;

    public BasicLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void log(String msg) {
        System.out.println("BasicLogger - before logging: " + msg);
        logger.log(msg);
        System.out.println("BasicLogger - after logging: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi alfasin, how can you apply different decorations to a logger using inheritance? For instance, if I have an HTMLLogger, BaseLogger, and XMLLogger, using composition, I can create objects with any combination of those three decorators. But with inheritance, how can I mix and match the different decorations? Unless I'm missing something, the only way I can see decorator working is with the composition methodology. Would you mind showing some examples of instantiating using inheritance? If I'm wrong about this, I'd be interested to see how it's done, and it would help others as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: After looking into this a bit more, I think it is incorrect. Composition must be used to properly implement the decorator pattern. See the [Horizontal and Vertical scrollbar example in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#First_example_.28window.2Fscrolling_scenario.29) and the Coffee example below it. Both examples demonstrate how one can instantiate a base, then add more functionality by adding the previous object into the constructor of the next. Decorator is all about extending at runtime instead of compile time. Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253 thanks for the link! the definition at the top says: "...either statically or dynamically..." which means that both compile-time (statically/composition) and run-time (dynamically/inheritance) implementations of the pattern are acceptable. The examples that you pointed me to are using inheritance and I agree with you and even take a step further by saying that I'd rather use composition over inheritance with most implementations of almost... anything :)  Thanks!

Comment: I addressed this further in the bottom portion of my answer. The advantage of the decorator pattern is that I can write, let's say, 4 implementations of a logger, but then at runtime mix and match the functionality by chaining the instantiated objects. With inheritance alone, wouldn't we have to create 16 different subclasses for each combination?  I think that's the main difference and advantage I see in the Wikipedia answers.  If I could sum everything up into one question, it would be this: What's the advantage of inheritance decorators over regular inheritance? Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: I don't think this is wrong, and the wiki article is confusing on some points, IMHO. It does clearly say the decorator pattern can be the same as inheritance. With that said, your answer definitely gives me a lot to think about. Hoping these comments have helped both you and the op think more deeply about the subject. +1

Comment: @jmort253 The only advantage I can see of inheritance over composition (not only in decorator pattern implementation but in general) is to prevent code/logic duplication. Usually you can do that with composition as well but sometimes you can’t. So other than these exceptions, I would choose composition for all the advantages you mentioned earlier!